# Execute WebInspect CLI from Pipeline

Tags: fortify

I'm trying to test the webInspect CLI. I execute the following command in PowerShell from an Azure Devops pipeline:

```
Set-Location 'E:\Fortify\Fortify WebInspect_22_2'
.\wi.exe -u <URL> -ps 1 -ab <USER>:<PASS>
```

But I get the following error

> this tool is not licensed for use by webinspect.

I do not have access to the server to test if this error also appears by opening a cmd but I have seen that other people have experienced the same error when executing from a pipeline.